# MongoDB Spring - Get a value dynamically

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, lookup, aggregation

I have the following documents each in a different collection

**assets**

```
{
  "_id": "1234",
  "name": "Needle",
  "initialStock": 20
},

{
  "_id": "12345",
  "name": "Serum",
  "initialStock": 5
}
```

**reserves**

```
{
  "_id: "12345,
  "from" : ISODate("2019-07-30T07:09:00.000Z"),
  "to" : ISODate("2019-08-30T11:00:00.000Z"),
  "assets": [
      {
     "_id": "1234",
     "assignedStock": 10
      },
     "_id": "12345",
     "assignedStock": 1
      }
    ]
}
```

How can I get the substraction of `assignedStock` and `initialStock` between 2 given dates? For example "I want to know the available stock of this asset between two dates (the from and to)".

How can this be done on Spring? (plain Mongo would give me a clue too).

My current code is the following but I am just getting an empty array at assets:

```
LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
       .from("assets")
       .localField("assets._id")
       .foreignField("_id")
       .as("assets");

Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("from")
       .gte(from)
       .and("to")
       .lte(to)
       .and("assets")
       .not().size(0)
       .elemMatch(
            Criteria.where("_id")
               .is(idAsset)
       );

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match(criteria), lookupOperation);
List<Document> results =
          this.mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "reserved", Document.class).getMappedResults();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky, Even I am new to MongoDB and find this query as challenging. However, I managed to write a query which returns you the desired output. I have used mongo playgroud to simulate the scenario you have specified in the question.

```js
db.reserves.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$assets"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$assets._id",
      sumAssigned: {
        $sum: "$assets.assignedStock"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "assets",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "asset_lookup"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      sumAssigned: 1,
      initialStock: {
        $sum: "$asset_lookup.initialStock"
      },
      availableStock: {
        $subtract: [
          "$sumAssigned",
          {
            $sum: "$asset_lookup.initialStock"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/h5eMWIE5q4p  // new solution

https://mongoplayground.net/p/r1bcoUjD3eG  // old solution

I have used aggregate pipe line with unwind, lookup and project operators. Hope it helps you.

Comment: there shouldnt be an aggregation to sum all the assignedStock from all the reserves documents that use an asset?

Comment: you can use $sum in aggregation if it is meeting your requirement. Unless you want to explain your problem with some example.

Comment: yes, my example is that I can have more than one reserve, and for examples two reserves can have the same asset with different assigned stock. For example a reserve 1 has 1 unit assigned of the asset with id 12345 and reserve 2 has 3 units assigned of the asset with id 12345. So now I'd need to know the result of the sum of total units assigned minus the result of stock which would be 20 - 4

Comment: @Wrong I have modified my answer, please check